# Can I ignore Xamarin.Forms error warnings in XAML code if the app still works?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using the latest stable build of Xamarin Forms (2.3.4.247), and I'm getting errors (in the form of green underlining) in my XAML code.

One of the errors, *"The type 'ContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built"*, seems to be a bug according to [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48322/contentpage-was-not-found-error-when-creating-new-xamarin-forms-portable-app), although this link talks about a much older version. When I rebuild the solution the green underlining and error messages disappear (until I edit the XAML page, and the errors reappear)

Another error I get is *"The Page is not usable as an object element because it is not public or doesn't define a public parameterless constructor or type converter"*. This error also disappears after a rebuild, but then reappears when I start editing the file.

The app works as intended on both Windows and Android (can't test IOS for now). Should I just ignore these errors?

On the second error, I am passing an object to the base constructor of my XAML page (that is not related to layout in anyway). Is this a problem?

My XAML class layout looks something like this:

```
public partial class BaseView : ContentPage { public BaseView(Obj obj) {}}
public partial class SubPage: BaseView { public SubPage(Obj ob) : base(obj) {}}
```

If I add parameterless overloads of the constructor, I get the same error message. Having read a bit on Google it seems that this error (the second one I mention) will stop any of the XAML from the child page being drawn. If there is a way to have XAML page hierarchies that can add their own objects to a parent, I would prefer that (i.e. I would like the child page's XAML to be drawn).

===== EDIT

It looks like Xamarin officially suggests passing data between pages via the page constructor [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Passing_Data_when_Navigating). This directly contradicts that warning messages should be avoided (at least that is what I have always thought).